# How to determine the real and imaginary parts of an image

Tags: java, fft

I am writing a classical FFT algorithm that I will integrate it into ImageJ. I have started writing the FFT by understanding the code online but I am have having trouble getting the imaginary and real parts of the original image. The original image is a dicom or raw image where it is a 256x256 matrix. The function that will do the FFT needs the real part and imaginary part as I am computing a 1D matrix FFT cause I don't really understand how to compute the 2D FFT. Also ImageJ- when it computes the FHT (which is a variance from the traditional FFT) it also does it by using a 1D array. I was hoping if anyone knows how to get imaginary and reals parts of original image pixel data.

My functions takes this as its parameter:

```
public void fft(double[] real, double[] image)
```

This is where ImageJ gets its data:

```
//get the data of the original image (pixel data).
float[] fft = (float[])getPixels();
```

This is what the fft (pixel data) produces:

```
......
57.0
39.0
45.0
50.0
18.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0 
...........
```

Comment: I believe that what you are looking for is `getComplexTransform()` method in the `FHT class`. See more about it in the [docs](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/process/FHT.html#getComplexTransform%28%29).

Comment: @Kyllopardiun yeah I had a look at that but does the complex transform produce the same results as the FFT transform like the image? If not how would I apply the FFT on the fft array without splitting it in to real and imaginary parts?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun yeah I don't think I can split fft array because the getComplexTransform produces a completely different picture than the actual FFT Window. Do you have any ideas on how I could write my FFT without splitting up the array?